# ColdFusion Builder/Eclipse: AutoComplete strings?

Tags: eclipse

When I type something like `model("` it adds the closing `")` that's great and all, but moving my hand over the right right arrow key makes it all worthless. How am I supposed to get to the end of the line? In NetBeans, typing `"` again afterwords just overwrites the auto-generated one so you don't get 2 closing quotes. Don't tell me they actually intend for me to press right twice?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly your issue, after typing in a generated Eclipse "pattern", like the "" or the method, you want to get at the end of it?

In this case, Most of these things are done with <kbd>Enter</kbd>, instead of adding the closing character again, for me. When in such conditions where Eclipse "feels" like you are filling in a gap, a form, pressing Enter terminates it, and goes to the end of the pattern you were into.

Let me know if I misunderstood something, however.

Comment: You understand it right, but your solution doesn't work. For example, Say I type `<cfset name="` then it inserts another `"` after my cursor, and I finish what I'm typing, so now it looks like `<cfset name="whatever|"` where `|` is my cursor. I want to move my cursor past that quote now. Hitting enter creates a newline.

Comment: @Mark - My solution works with Eclipse, while editing Java code, for example. I thought it would apply also for your case, but it seems that not, I'm sorry.

Comment: Maybe I'll download Eclipse and install ColdFusion as an addon, rather than this standalone thingy....wonder if that'll work.

Comment: @Mark - it will probably be same, the addon will take the editing role, so will probably make the same behavior, but worth a try indeed.